# A button bar on demand, in wpf

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

I have a tree like structure (containing nodes and edges) and I want that on clicking a certain node, a styled button bar slides out (from the node) containing max 2-4 buttons. On clicking any other part of the window, the bar should slide in. This, has to follow the MVVM pattern so I understand, the button bar has to be a custom control that would be bound to the particular node's ViewModel. However, I have no idea as to how to achieve the slide in-out effect.
Any guidance/pointers regarding this will be appreciated.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your custom control inside a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control. You can then set the PopupAnimation to Slide, which would cause you control to slide into view.

The following XAML defines a Popup that slides into view next to a ToggleButton control. The Popup is opened when the button is toggled - you'd need to change this behaviour so the Popup opens when your node is clicked. When the Popup loses focus it closes.

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton>Click to show</ToggleButton>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton}"
           StaysOpen="False"
           Placement="Right"
           PopupAnimation="Slide">

        <!-- Your custom control goes here -->

    </Popup>
```

There are other animation effects you can play with - Fade and Scroll. If you need something more complex, you will need to look at setting up a StoryBoard.

Comment: Bulls Eye! Thats what I needed! I will experimant with it more though.
Request you to update your code to put the ending quotes (") in the IsOpen property.

Comment: thanks for the answer it is working but the pop up appears and fades very fast. Is there a way to delay it a little?